# Hibernate Search Enum Query Multiple Values

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have an Indexed enum with multiple values Active, Pending, Pulled. I was to devise a query that will get only Active and Pulled, but not Pending.

```
junction = junction.must(
                    qb.keyword().onField("itemStatus").ignoreFieldBridge()
                            .matching("active pulled").createQuery());
```

the query above is my first stab at it, but this doesn't return anything unless I change the query to only active or change the junction to a should. I basically want a must with an and condition...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to separate the two queries for the different matching status:

```
Query itemStatusQuery = queryBuilder
    .bool()             
        .should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("itemStatus").matching("active").createQuery())
        .should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("itemStatus").matching("pulled").createQuery())
    .createQuery();

 junction = junction.must(itemStatusQuery);
```

Alternatively you might be able to use a `must().not()`. See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#_combining_queries

Comment: I tried this but I have a third criteria that is in it that is a must. so what ends up happening is the should in the itemStatus statements work but the query also returns all items that match the third criteria which returns pending items, but I don't want pending items. The selection is variable too.. sometimes I want active, pending, or sometimes just pending. It depends on what the user selected.